# Is it halal in Islam to work as a web/graphics designer?

Tags: halal-haram, work

As a graphics or web designer,we have to work with picture/video for buyer/site,we know animal picture and others are not halal so at web design most of the buyer will want women picture or videos to add.and for this the payment which will given to me haram or halal?

Comment: "we know animal picture and others are not halal" if you can add your sources here, that would be better.

Comment: Because of this Hadith: The Prophet said, 'Angels do not enter a house in which there are dogs or pictures'. (Sahih-Al-Bukhari, 7.833, Narrated by Abu Talha)

Comment: Is this hadith make it haraam? it doesn't say never use these. It says, if you do this, this will be consequence. If you have pictures in your house, angels do not enter your house.

Comment: If your expectations are of this kind, why you ask then? The answer should be obvious. However I'm not certain whether your expectation of what your job will be and what you will sell or do are really correct.

Answer (score 2):

Some pictures have specific copyright for author. For example pictures from [this reference](https://blog.bufferapp.com/free-image-sources-list) has public copyright issue and you have not ask owner for privileges.

Using pictures that are free source has no problem. Islam is compatible with modern world then leave these ideas and use your creativity and intelligent to make as best work as you can.

These ideas only make Muslims weak and useless in modern world as we see today!!

PS : If your photo doesn't violent por_no_graph and Copyright law then you are allowed.

Comment: Yeah, tis an important point as you said "Some pictures have specific copyright for author". I likewise add: (not haram pictures such ... haram scenes...). Thanks for logical answer dear HOPE.

Comment: Very bad answer without any references from Quran o Hadith or scholar's fatwa.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are not for arguments and debating controversial points.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question as I am also Full Stack Web Developer

The thing is the prohibition of using pictures of women that lead someone to sin that is totally prohibited so using any picture of women in website is considered as a sin.

Using Pictures of humans like men so different Ulma has their opinions some says not to use at all and some says if pictures snapped through camera **it is not changing the creation of Allah** it is exact same replicate of human so it is okay while for me second opinion seems logical and make sense

So you can use pictures of Human (Males)  you can use Pictures of Animals and any creation but make sure not drawing but snapped via camera which makes absolutely same as the creation is so Insha Allah there will not be any sin or Haram...

And Allah Knows the Best

Answer (score -4):

The art of drawing the animate beings if the three-dimensional haram unanimously. Who transfer this consensus is "Nawawi".

If hand painting on panels, walls, clothes, etc., it is also forbidden by the majority of "Oulama":

> Saying peace be upon him: "Those who make images punished on the Day of Resurrection, it is said to them: Bring to life what you have created." Narrated by Muslim from Ibn 'Umar.
>
> Muslim narrated as well as Saeed Bin Abu Hassan said: A man came to Ibn Abbas said: I am a man drawing these images, he said to him: come closer to me, he did, and then said: come closer to me, he did until he put his hand on his head, he said, : i tell you what I heard from the Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him? I heard the Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him says: "Every photographer in the hell, makes him all the image forms a breath, Freshen up him in hell". And in the Sahih Bukhari, he said to him: "Woe, if you refuse but to do so, then do it with this trees, everything without spirit."

This shows the permission to draw all that is empty of spirit like trees, stone, and rivers

والله تعالى أعلم

Comment: Why still downvote ?

Comment: your answer does not address original question: "Is it halal in Islam to work as a web/graphics designer?"